# Source for standardized audio files for an experiment in German

Tags: experimental-psychology, auditory-discrimination

I need some audio files for an experiment. In this experiment, numbers will be played to the subjects via headphones, so I need sound files with spoken numbers. Actually, a single file with a sequence of numbers is fine.

The goal is to produce a similar experiment as the one by Neil W. Mulligan (The Role of Attention During Encoding in Implicit and Explicit Memory). In this experiment, the material from the test set developed by Blaxton (1989) were used.

Is there any standardized database for this kind of things? I know there are standardized face databases, but I am not sure about sound files and googling did not help.

The problem is that the subjects will be from Germany, so I need the numbers in German.

Comment: do you need the digits(Ziffern) from 0-9,
or whole numbers e.g from 1-9999

Comment: You can try http://www.dwds.de/ (e.g., http://www.dwds.de/?qu=eins&view=1). Their audio samples sound quite good, although I do not know whether this is a 'standardized' corpus. However, it is in German only, i.e., you need to know the German translation of the numbers you want to have. Furthermore, I do not know how to rip the audio samples from the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=de&q="1"
```

or this:

```
http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=de&q="11;27;39;81;32;53"
```

At the moment, I can't test if it pronounces the full numbers right, but I hope it will work.

I think the pronunciation of higher numbers are better if you write them like this: *NineHundredSixtySix*

Comment: These audio samples are not spoken but generated by speech processors. Expecially the larger numbers sound quite strange.

Comment: 1. i think this could be even better because there are no emotions etc..
2.see edit..